# Im having a problem getting the main class of my intelliJ project

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I need to Get a main class [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GlKTW.png)

I would then assume I need to put in the directory of the main class so i do [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J5EHl.png)
But that gives me a separate error.

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lb6xw.png) You can see a clearer image of the code if that helps.

[Would this be a main class?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6PvWM.png)
and if so what would i put here: [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OsnNS.png)

```
import net.fabricmc.api.ModInitializer;

public class SwordsAndShields implements ModInitializer {
    @Override
    public void onInitialize() {

    }
```

Comment: That (`SwordsAndShields`) isn't a main class.  This question doesn't make much sense to me.  If you are asking what a main class should look like; see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/application/index.html.  The `HelloWorldApp` class is a main class.

Comment: do the links not work?

Comment: Ok ive added images and changed it to a main class

Comment: Your main class is `SwordsAndShields` but as you can see clearly in the error that you posted, you are trying to run `Swords_and_shields` - fix it.

Comment: Ive gotten the same error from that

Comment: According to the code on the screenshots, your class' name is "sas". Try running the program via green arrow in the gutter. Like that: https://i.imgur.com/nQTmspd.png

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/5x8OiUK theres another error here

Comment: ok now i have another error as i fixed the other one

Comment: There is an apostrophe in the wrong place in /temp and i dont know how to get rid of it.        [https://imgur.com/CCphN6z]

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VhcsJ.png) Where it says cp at the top right be sure it ends with .main

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).